# Dog licking herself when she can't hold it at night

Tags: dogs, behavior

My dog is an 11 year old terrier. She sleeps next to my bed at night and occasionally she wakes me up with the sound of slurping while she is licking her private area. I just let her keep looking herself but then notice when I let her out in the morning she doesn't need to use the bathroom. Is she licking up her urine over night? I try to get 8 hours of sleep so it's usually been 8 hores since she was out last. I tried not feeding her water at night but she still does this occasionally. If she is doing what she's doing I'm wondering if she just doesn't want to or can't wake me up. I would prefer if she woke me up when she's having trouble holding it over night. What do I do? Is there any way to stop this behavior?

Comment: I'm no vet but maybe she has an infection down there, get her examined by a vet...

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty unusual for a dog to lick away their own urine, its something i've never come across. Its something mothers generally do to their pups in the earlier stages of their lives but generally stops between 5-8 weeks.

Generally when a dog obsessively licks an area its to clean it from infection or a wound so I would get a vet to examine her. The licks can foster all sorts of weird noises so that doesn't worry too much. But again, get a vet to examine her.

I would also try to put a routine into her bathroom breaks, one in the morning and one before you go to bed and she will eventually sync her bladder to this and learn to hold it until then. Do this without fail.